# What runway alignment should I expect from a straight-in approach?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, iaps

More precisely, in the case when a straight-in approach is present, what is the maximum angle between the final approach course and the runway heading for a straight-in minimum apply?

I had thought it is 15° for GPS IAP and 30° for others. However, when I looked at [RNAV (GPS) RWY 28L @ KMRY](http://flightaware.com/resources/airport/MRY/IAP/RNAV+(GPS)+Y+RWY+28L/pdf), the angle is |279.4° - 261°| = 18.4° > 15°. Is there any other rule that applies, or is this simply an exception?

Note that on IAP runway diagram (bottom-left), there is usually an arrow with a distance from FAF to MAP and course direction, and they are omitted here.

[image: RNAV (GPS) RWY 28L @ KMRY]

Comment: According to the FAA Instrument Procedures Handbook, [Chapter 4](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/instrument_procedures_handbook/media/chapter_4.pdf), p 4-63: `For a non-vertically guided straight-in RNAV (GPS) approach, the final approach course must be aligned within 15° of the extended runway centerline.` That doesn't conclusively answer the question, but does lead me to wonder if the LP approach is considered straight in here, but the LNAV approach is essentially considered a circling approach. But then why have the LNAV option at all?

Comment: Also I noticed that on G1000/GFC700 WAAS-equipped database, there is no procedure for LP approach, only LNAV.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an interesting question because it turns out that RNAV approach criteria aren't defined in the [TERPS](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/FAA_Order_8260.3C.pdf) as you would expect. Instead, there's a separate FAA order [8260.58](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/FAA_Order_8260.58A.pdf) for RNAV approaches.

The TERPS does indeed give 30° as the maximum offset for most approaches (e.g. section 4-2-4) and 15° for VOR/DME RNAV approaches (section 13-3-4), but VOR/DME RNAV approaches are still based on ground stations (section 13-1):

> VOR/DME RNAV systems use signals based solely upon a VOR/DME, VORTAC,
>   or TACAN reference facility. These systems use radials and distances
>   from a reference facility to compute position and flight track
>   information

On the other hand, the criteria for 'true' RNAV approaches not based on ground stations are defined in 8260.58 and they allow for offsets up to 30°  for approaches without vertical guidance (section 3-2-2):

> a. Offset. When the final course must be offset, it may be offset up
>   to 30 degrees (published separately from vertically guided) when the
>   following conditions are met:
>
> (1) Offset ≤ 5 degrees. Align the course through LTP.
>
> (2) Offset > 5 degrees and 10 ≤ degrees. The course must
>   cross the runway centerline extended at least 1500 feet prior to LTP
>   (5200 feet maximum).
>
> (3) Offset > 10 degrees and ≤ 20 degrees. The
>   course must cross the runway centerline extended at least 3000 feet
>   prior to LTP (5200 feet maximum). For offsets > 15 degrees, CAT C/D
>   minimum published visibility 1 SM, minimum HAT of 300 feet.
>
> (4) Offset 20 to 30 degrees (CAT A/B only). The course must cross the runway centerline extended at least 4500 feet prior to the LTP (5200 feet
>   maximum).

Since the approach you showed doesn't have vertical guidance, it would fall under this section and therefore the offset of 16.76° marked on the plate is normal.